# MySQL, can destination table be named by the query?

Tags: php, mysql

We're simplifying and organizing a messy taxonomy system. I have about 100 unique terms across three source-table fields that need to generate new terms in various output-table fields (three output fields, about 8 terms each)

```
source_table
id | term1         | term2   | term3
1  | Iraq          |         | 
2  | Asia          |         | Economy
3  | Wall St       | Asia    | 
4  | France        | Economy | US News
5  | Daily Report  | Labor   |

lookup_table
id | in_term          | output_field   | output_term
1  | Iraq             | regions        | Middle East
2  | Asia             | regions        | Asia
3  | Wall St          | topics         | Economy
4  | France           | regions        | Europe
5  | Daily Report     | shows          | The Daily Report 
6  | Economy          | topics         | Economy
7  | Labor            | topics         | Labor
8  | US News          | regions        | North America

output_table
id | regions               | topics  | shows
1  | Middle East           |         | 
2  | Asia                  | Economy |
3  | Asia                  | Economy |
4  | Europe, North America | Economy | 
5  |                       | Labor   | The Daily Report
```

Is there a way to have the specified output field be generated from the lookup, or will I need to do individual update passes for each output field? And how would I structure this command either way?

A MySQL solution is preferred, but if has to be implemented in PHP that would would too.

Comment: it is really not clear what output is needed.

Comment: The output needs to go to a specified field on the output table. But the output field that is specified is part depends on the input term. That is, if the input term is "Iraq," the output table field will be "region," and the output term will be "Middle East."

Comment: It is not clear why lookup_table seems having columns ID and output_term - will your task be still achievable without these columns?

Comment: lookup_table does not need the ID. However, output term **is** needed; for instance, if the input_term is `Iraq`, the output_term is `Middle East`, then `Middle East` is what will appear in the output_table.

Answer (score 0):

In case if I understand properly and if `output_term` is not field from `lookup_table` and you need to join source and output using ID :

```
select case output_field 
   when 'regions' then regions 
   when 'topics'  then topics
   else  shows end
from source_table join output_table using(id) 
join lookup_table on term1=in_term
where source_table.id = 1;
```

Comment: I think this is very close! All it needs is to use the lookup_table.output_terms in the output_table fields. And the last line — doesn't that mean this will work on the first input row only?

Answer (score 0):

I will add another attempt, assuming that 'output_table' is not input data but actual required output:

```
select id, l1.output_term regions, l2.output_term topics, l3.output_term shows
from source_table 
left join lookup_table l1 on l1.output_field='regions' 
          and l1.in_term in (term1, term2, term3)
left join lookup_table l2 on l2.output_field='topics' 
          and l2.in_term in (term1, term2, term3)
left join lookup_table l3 on l3.output_field='shows' 
          and l3.in_term in (term1, term2, term3);
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this as three distinct queries, one per out_field, because I found the input table to be very thin on data and I was ending up with incomplete rows on output, when I need completed rows. Doing the queries individually by output_field allowed me to monitor the results count and see how badly off the results were. Also my output_table already existed so I ran this as an UPDATE.

```
UPDATE output_table out 
INNER JOIN (SELECT source_table.id AS sid, GROUP_CONCAT(out_term) AS terms
FROM source_table source
  INNER JOIN input_table
  ON (in.in_term=source.t1 
  OR in.in_term=source.t2 
  OR in.in_term=source.t3) 
  AND output_field='regions' 
  GROUP BY sid) AS map
ON map.sid=out.id
SET out.regions = map.terms;
```

Queries for topics and shows worked exactly the same.

In subsequent queries I could grab all output_tables for example `WHERE region IS NULL`, and run the above query again, but instead of matching on input_terms, I could match on headlines, body, tags, or other fields, hoping to find a random match so I could add a region tag where none was found in the input_terms.